# Plotly.js - Get 4 y values for each x in a stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, stacked-chart, plotly.js

I have plotted a stacked bar chart for 4 data values that I have for every U.S. state. The CSV file I have been working off of looks like this:

[image]

Here's the JS code I wrote for the stacked bar chart:

```js
// Read the data from CSV
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krithikaragha/ResPy/master/Flask%20App/static/data/tobacco_use_by_state.csv', function(data) {

    var chartData = []; // Array containing all the traces
    function makeTrace(d) {    // Function to make all 50 traces
        return {
            x: ["Smokes Everyday", "Smokes Somedays", "Former Smoker", "Never Smoked"],
            y: [d.smokesEveryday, d.smokesSomedays, d.formerSmoker, d.neverSmoked],
            name: d.state,
            type: 'bar'
        }   
    }

    // Loop through all rows of the data
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        // Call makeTrace to create a trace with index i
        chartData.push(makeTrace(data[i]));

        // Define a chart layout
        var layout = {
            barmode: 'stack',
            width: 1200,
            height: 800
        };

        // Plot the stacked bar chart 
        Plotly.newPlot('bar', chartData, layout);
    }
});
```

The resulting stacked bar chart ended up looking like this:
[image]

The result I want to achieve is: I want each U.S. state to have its own bar which is stacked with respective 4 values (smokesEveryday, smokesSomedays, formerSmoker and neverSmoked)

Is there any way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself.

Turns out, I had to make four separate traces for each of the 4 values I needed. So I looped through the data and created arrays for each column - smokedEveryday, smokesSomedays, formerSmoker and neverSmoked and a last array states to hold the state's abbreviations.

Then I created 4 individual traces with x-axis holding the states array and y-axis holding the respective smoking array.

Here's the modified code snippet:

```js
// Read the data from CSV
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krithikaragha/ResPy/master/Flask%20App/static/data/tobacco_use_by_state.csv', function(data) {

    var states = [];
    var smokesEveryday = []; 
    var smokesSomedays = [];
    var formerSmoker = [];
    var neverSmoked = [];

    // Loop through all rows of the data
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        states.push(data[i].abbr);
        smokesEveryday.push(data[i].smokesEveryday);
        smokesSomedays.push(data[i].smokesSomedays);
        formerSmoker.push(data[i].formerSmoker);
        neverSmoked.push(data[i].neverSmoked);
    }

    var smokesEverydayTrace = {
        x: states,
        y: smokesEveryday,
        name: 'Smokes Everyday',
        type: 'bar'
    };

    var smokesSomedaysTrace = {
        x: states,
        y: smokesSomedays,
        name: 'Smokes Somedays',
        type: 'bar'
    };

    var formerSmokerTrace = {
        x: states,
        y: formerSmoker,
        name: 'Former Smoker',
        type: 'bar'
    };

    var neverSmokedTrace = {
        x: states,
        y: neverSmoked,
        name: 'Never Smoked',
        type: 'bar'
    };
      
    var data = [neverSmokedTrace, formerSmokerTrace, smokesSomedaysTrace, smokesEverydayTrace];
    
    var layout = {
        barmode: 'stack', 
        title: "Percentage of Tobacoo Use by State",
        xaxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Tobacco Use"
            }, 
            tickangle: 45
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Percentage"
            }
        },
        bargap: 0.4,
        width: 1250,
        height: 800
    };
    
    Plotly.newPlot('bar', data, layout);
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking just for this :)